# XMPPHP Could not connect after timeout

Tags: gmail, xmpp, chat, google-talk

I am trying to create a web based PHP application which can allow chat to my Gmail friends. Something like meebo.com. I downloaded XMPPHP, and executed on localhost, and it is working fine, but when I uploaded everything to Yahoo Small business web hosting, it is throwing connection timeout error.

Do anyone else faced such problem. I heard many of them did, but no one have any solution yet.

Any suggestion will be very helpful. I am new to XMPP clients.

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas...

How are you trying to connect to the XMPP server? With XMPPHP you may use two classes which are

1. XMPPHP
2. XMPPHP_BOSH

You might try both, since they work on different ports (XMPPHP for example on 5222 and XMPPHP_BOSH on 80). So if this is a port issue, trying XMPPHP_BOSH would be an idea. You will need to find out though if this is supported by the XMPP server you are trying to connect to. And if so, you need to know the url the server exposes the BOSH service on.

Anyways, I would recommend to check out what kind of 'restrictions' there are in Yahoo Small business web hosting and on the side of the XMPP server.

If you intend to check XMPPHP_BOSH out, consider this issue to make it work: [Issue 47: Http-bind error](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/issues/detail?id=47). All in all XMPPHP seems very buggy and incomplete...